# my js code gives me an error saying that "property is not defined" eventhough it exists in my object

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qe59.png)I'm getting Uncaught TypeError, and couldn't figure why..the property is defined and tried to delete "[cardId]" but it didn't work either.. my problem is within the flipCard function.

```
var cards = [{
                rank: "queen",
                suit: "hearts",
                cardImage:"images/queen-of-hearts.png"
             },
             {
                rank: "queen",
                suit: "diamonds",
                cardImage:"images/queen-of-diamonds.png"
             },
             {
                rank:"king",
                suit: "hearts",
                cardImage:"images/king-of-hearts.png"
             },
             {
                rank:"king",
                suit:"diamonds",
                cardImage:"images/king-of-diamonds.png"
             }
            ];
var cardsInPlay = [];
var checkForMatch = function()
{
    this.setAttribute('src',cards[cardId].cardImage);
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2)
    {
        if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1])
        {
            alert("You found a match!!");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Sorry, try again");
        }
    }
}
var flipCard = function()
{
    var cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank);
    cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
    console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
    console.log(cards[cardId].suit);
    checkForMatch();
}


var createBoard = function()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
        cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', cards[i]);
        cardElement.addEventListener("click", flipCard);
        document.getElementById('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
    }
}
createBoard();
```

when I click on the card it should be turned and show me either a king or queen.

Comment: What's the error exactly?

Comment: what is `this`? You have `this.getAttribute('data-id')` but it isn't clear from the code you posted if its associated with an html element or what

Comment: @GMaiolo I just add a picture show the error..

Comment: @chiliNUT it's associated with img as it is in createBoard function

Comment: `cardId` is a property, not an `index`, that's the specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using `this.getAttribute` but that does not exist in this context. I'm guessing you are needing to pass the event target. But I'm not sure how you are calling this function. I'm just taking a shot in the dark but I think this could fix it

```
var flipCard = function(event) {
  const element = event.target;
  var cardId = element.getAttribute('data-id');

  console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank);
  cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
  console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
  console.log(cards[cardId].suit);
  checkForMatch();
}
```

So if your card element looks like this `<div class="card" data-id="card_1"> Card 1</div>`

You can attach an event listener to call `flipCard`

```
const card = document.querySelector('.card');
card.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
```

Comment: I'm calling the function from within another function which is createBoard.. the event listener is in the createBoard function.

Comment: Passing the event target is still the issue here. Also you had `this.setAttribute` in your match method, also does not exist in the context you are calling.

Comment: Make sure you pass `element` /or  `event.target` and the `cardId` to the methods that need them. Here is a fiddle for you to take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/b0whp15v/

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes in the createBoard function , and in the flipCard function.. and now it works the way it was supposed to.. here's my code after the chagnes

```
var cards = [{
                rank: "queen",
                suit: "hearts",
                cardImage:"images/queen-of-hearts.png"
             },
             {
                rank: "queen",
                suit: "diamonds",
                cardImage:"images/queen-of-diamonds.png"
             },
             {
                rank:"king",
                suit: "hearts",
                cardImage:"images/king-of-hearts.png"
             },
             {
                rank:"king",
                suit:"diamonds",
                cardImage:"images/king-of-diamonds.png"
             }
            ];
var cardsInPlay = [];
var numberOfGames = 0;
var numberOfwins = 0;
var numberOfLosts =0;
var checkForMatch = function()
{
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2)
    {
        if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1])
        {
            alert("You found a match!!");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Sorry, try again");
        }
    }
}
var flipCard = function()
{
    var cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank);
    cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
    console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
    console.log(cards[cardId].suit);
    this.setAttribute('src',cards[cardId].cardImage);
    checkForMatch();
}


var createBoard = function()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
        cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i);
        cardElement.addEventListener("click", flipCard);
        document.getElementById('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
    }
}
createBoard();
```